# append d3 text to existing html div

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a div in html that looks like

```
<div class="newfield col-sm-4">
            <h2>42</h2>
            <h3>Appending above</h3>
</div>
```

And code in D3(v4) that looks like

```
var word = "somestring";
d3.select('.newfield')
.append("h2")
.html(word.join('<br/>'));
```

I want the D3 text of "somestring to take place of '42' in the original html.

So the end result will look like

```
<div class="newfield col-sm-4">
            <h2>somestring</h2>
            <h3>Appending above</h3>
</div>
```

My current D3 code is not appending anything to the screen.
My scripts are imported in this order

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/customd3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done such a task with plain Javascript and not involved an external library.

But if it has to be done using D3:

```js
d3.selectAll('.newfield h2')
  .text("somestring")
  //.append("br") //not really necessary!
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div class="newfield col-sm-4">
  <h2>42</h2>
  <h3>Appending above</h3>
</div>
```